# How do I install pyenchant in CentOS?

Tags: python, linux, centos, pyenchant, enchant

I am using `CentOS 5` with `Python 2.7` installed. I am trying to install `pyenchant` library, but failed in all the cases.

1. Used `pip install pyenchant` - This produced the following error -

`AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libenchant.so.1: undefined symbol: enchant_dict_add`

2. Used `yum install enchant` - This produced the following error -

`http://mirror.nexcess.net/CentOS/5.11/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found`.

3. Downloaded `pyenchant-1.6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` from this [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/1.6.6). Used `pip install pyenchant-1.6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl` - This produced the same error again.

`AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libenchant.so.1: undefined symbol: enchant_dict_add`

Is there any other way I can install this library?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your OS to centos 8 and test stages agian.